# Terraform fails to install haproxy on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy, terraform

I'm using Terraform v0.9.11 (running on a CentOS7 server) and I'm simply trying to create a digital ocean machine and install haproxy there.

If I choose to create a CentOS7 machine the whole process works without problem.
If I choose to create an Ubuntu 16.04 machine the process is unable to install haproxy after successfully building the Ubuntu 16.04 machine. The only way for me to be able to install haproxy is to login to the Ubuntu 16.04 machine and manually install haproxy there.

This is my .tf file:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "haproxy-www" {
image = "ubuntu-16-04-x64"
name = "haproxy-www"
region = "lon1"
size = "512mb"
private_networking = true
ssh_keys = [
  "${var.ssh_fingerprint}"
]

connection {
  user = "root"
  type = "ssh"
  private_key = "${file("${var.pvt_key}")}"
  timeout = "2m"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
       "apt-get update",
       "apt-get -y install haproxy" 
          ]
       }
   }
```

Haproxy installation fails with the following message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. 
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
haproxy : Depends: liblua5.3-0 but it is not installable
```

However.....if I login to the Terraform-created machine and manually run

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install haproxy
```

haproxy get installed without problems...!

I noticed the following : 
-if I try to (unsuccessfully) use the above Terraform remote-exec then the following repos are used

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security
etc...
```

-when I login and (successfully) install haproxy the following repos are used

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security
http://lon1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial
http://lon1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates
etc...
```

Is my Terraform configuration wrong? Please note that the same configuration (obviously with yum instead of apt-get and with image="centos-7-2-x64" instead of image="ubuntu-16-04-x64") perfectly works for CentOS7.

Thank you very much in advance for your precious help!!!
Ely

Comment: how are the digitalocean repos showing up when you're logging in? I don't imagine those are included in the default ubuntu repo list.

Comment: you could add additional remote-exec lines to add those repos before attempting apt-get install.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
        "sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:vbernat/haproxy-1.5",
        "sudo apt-get update",
        "sudo apt-get -y install haproxy"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi RaGe, thank you for your help. Your suggestion (which is publicly available and refers to Ubuntu 14.04 rather than 16.04) was the first thing I tried, and it failed with the same error. Besides I'm not happy to use non-officially maintained repos like vbernat/haproxy-1.5. I cannot see reasons why the same commands which work after I login are the ones which fail if I run them remotely through Terraform. I'm stubbornly working on that :-)

Comment: fair point about non-official. Interestingly though, there does seem to be an official haproxy package for xenial.. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/haproxy

Comment: as for your logging in, maybe there is something in your profile that adds additional repos when you log in?

Comment: There is also a possibility of a race condition, maybe terraform provisioner attempts to run while creation activities like adding repos is still going on. I would attempt to debug by adding a 2 minute or so sleep as the first inline command.